# c++ properties don't go through methods?

Tags: visual-c++

I thought properties in c++ could be used to set variables with methods while still maintaining the dot notation for access. Am I wrong?

```
class Class {
private:
    int _number;

    void putNumber(int number) {
        if (number < 10) _number = 0;
        else _number = number;
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

public:
    __declspec(property(get = getNumber,put = putNumber)) int number;
};

main()
{
    Class classObj;
    classObj.number = 2;
    std::cout << classObj.number;
}
```

Shouldn't the source code output 0? It outputs 2 though..

How can I achieve the effect I am looking for? Of maintaining the dot notation but going through setter and getters for access?

Comment: This is not standard C++

Comment: There's no such thing as "properties" in C++. If you want such a feature, you can write your own proxy class that overloads a `T &` conversion operator, but generally it's considered poor design if you need to expose data members directly. Instead, try to work out what your class really represents and expose a high-level interface only.

Comment: In addition to what Kerrek said, your proxy class would need a `T` conversion operator and a custom `operator=`.  But not a `T&` conversion operator, since that wouldn't let you intercept "put" operations.

Answer (score 1):

While everyone is correct it is not standard, providing you are compiling with Visual Studio and you don't care about running on any other OS, go ahead. If you are compiling on VS, you should have got this error:

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'Class::putNumber' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Class'
```

Your getter/setter methods are private and therefore can't be accessed, you need to modify your code thus:

```
class Class {
private:
    int _number;
public:

    void putNumber(int number) {
        if (number < 10) _number = 0;
        else _number = number;
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

    __declspec(property(get = getNumber,put = putNumber)) int number;
};
```

Though judging by your lack of compile error, I suspect you are not compiling in Visual Studio.

Comment: Or he ignored a compile error, and ran whatever version last compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx), access to the "virtual member" is converted to a call to the accessor function.

This suggests that the accessor function needs to be accessible to the caller.  Try making them public?